# Spotify is making crackling sound every 5-10 seconds

Tags: windows-10, audio, spotify

I just build a desktop PC, everything is good except Spotify! it is making crackling sound every 5-10 seconds, almost like this: https://youtu.be/SzM2KaMszvc?t=26

Everything else works PERFECT!, Games works fine, Visual Studio compilation works fast, Chrome with 70 tabs works fine (ok maybe not 70 tabs... but you get the point).

I have followed troubleshooting instructions here: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Annoying-cracking-noise-on-every-song/td-p/4768683 but nop, no effect.

Things I have tried:

- Disable audio enhancement
- Set to 'Do Nothing' in Communication setting
- Toggle hardware acceleration
- High quality streaming
- Download playlist to local
- Change speaker
- Disable NVIDIA HD sound
- Disable Mic
- Reinstall Spotify
- Disable Windows Defender

This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Do you have all audio drivers up to date? Could be something simple like reinstalling the audio drivers. In Device Manager try disabling Nvidia HD sounds drivers too.

Comment: Is the PC connected via Wifi to the Internet? May be in combination with Bluetooth headphones? Spotify on PC does not really "stream" audio instead it load every few seconds a large block of data. May be the Wifi frequencies cause those crackling sounds...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Premium-Crackling-Stuttering/td-p/104295)?

Comment: Yeah I have tried fiddling around  with all imaginable settings as suggested in those threads..., disable enhancement, uninstall drivers, update latest drivers for everything, replacing my speaker, none works... now I only listen Spotify from mobile phone.

Comment: @Robert I am not using wireless headphone.., I connect my earphone directly to the headphone jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after weeks of trying, I finally **found the cause and the fix**.

**Flash BIOS/UEFI Firmware to the latest.**

I have always reluctant to meddle with BIOS/UEFI because one wrong move could brick the motherboard. But due to frustration I finally decided it is worth a try.

I am using ASUS ROG Strix B550-XE motherboard and was using the original BIOS firmware that came factory fitted with the motherboard. When I check at ASUS website there is a bunch of updates for the BIOS, mine was version 0305 released on July 2020.

So I **flashed the BIOS from version 0305 to version 2423**. It has been 2 months now and Spotify never once crackle or having any issues. I waited 2 months to confirm this is the actual fix.

Hopefully that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. All other apps worked fine with the Bluetooth speaker, except Spotify.

After several bouts with headache (literally and figuratively, because the crackling sound triggered my migraine), I solved the problem this morning.

I don't know the technical aspects, but in my PC, I changed the Output Settings from:

- 2 channels, 16 bit, 44100 Hz

To:

- 1 channel, 16 bit, 44100 Hz

I don't understand these things but it worked.